# How to make Polymer 2.x Function async

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, polymer-2.x

I am trying to use the Shape Detection API (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/shape-detection) and am getting an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

After going through the Polymer 2.x docs (https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/api/namespaces/Polymer.Async) I get the following:

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
  this.initImageDetection();
}

initImageDetection() {
  const barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector({
    formats: [
      'code_128'
    ]
  });
  try {
    const barcodes = await barcodeDetector.detect(image);
    barcodes.forEach(barcode => console.log(barcode));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Barcode detection failed:', e);
  }
}
```

This pattern also failed with the same error:

```
this.async(() => {
  const barcodes = await barcodeDetector.detect(image)
  barcodes.forEach(barcode => console.log(barcode)
)});
```

Also, running `initImageDetection` prefixed with `async` and running from a `paper-button` after the DOM is loaded.

```
async initImageDetection() {
  ...
}
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: BarcodeDetector is not defined

How do I properly make a function async in Polymer 2.x?

How can I instantiate BarcodeDetector in Polymer 2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async functionName() {
  // function code here
}
```

Is the proper way to set async functions in Polymer. However, the `BarcodeDetector` object is hidden behind a flag in Chrome, so must be enabled in `chrome://flags` `Experimental Web Platform features` before using.